# math.pow alternative in Lua?

Tags: lua

I cannot use `math.pow(x,y)` in Lua.

I don't know why, it says syntax error.

`math.sin(f)` and `math.cos(f)` works however.

Is there other alternative for `math.pow()` in Lua?

Comment: I've updated my answer. `math.pow()` is deprecated, but it still exists. It shouldn't cause a syntax error. Please update your question to show the exact code that produces the error, as well as the text of the error message. You almost certainly made some other error.

Comment: still can if you are using LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Lua's `math.pow()` function is deprecated as of release 5.3, as documented [here](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#8.2).  But it still exists in the latest release (up to and including 5.4.6).

If you're getting a syntax error, it's due to some other problem. Please update your question to show us the exact code that produces the error, as well as the error message.

In any case, you should use the built-in `^` exponentiation operator rather than the `math.pow()` function.

(Unlike C and some other languages, Lua uses `~` as the bitwise xor operator.)

Answer (score 1):

In Lua 5.4.6, `math.pow` exists only if Lua is compiled with `LUA_COMPAT_MATHLIB`.  Otherwise, you get

```
Lua 5.4.6  Copyright (C) 1994-2023 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> math.pow
nil
```

Comment: Indeed. This is true for since Lua 5.3+. But `LUA_COMPAT_MATHLIB` is turned on by default in luaconf.h.