# Is there any ways to use math.pow in lua 5.3?

Tags: lua

I have found an [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53184121/math-pow-alternative-in-lua) about this, now I have discovered a syntax error for this really useful built-in function. *My code is simple but the error isn't*:

```lua
print(math.pow(10, 2))
```

> Error: File:2: attempt to call a nil value (field 'pow')

If math.pow no longer exist in Lua 5.3, maybe I have to create a new function for real. Still, I want to be a lazy donkey :)

Comment: `math.pow` is deprecated in Lua 5.3 but is still available when Lua 5.3 is built with compatibility flags, which is the default in the lua.org distribution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`math.pow` was replaced by the `^` operator: `10 ^ 2`.

If you have many calls to math.pow, you can simply add the function:

```lua
math = math or {}
function math.pow(a, b)
    return a ^ b
end
```