# Calculation result different in javacript and lua

Tags: javascript, node.js, math, lua, operators

I'm currently creating my own bot made with NodeJS and having a issue where my formula won't calculate the same way it does in Lua

Here is a example:

```
XP = 79878

math.floor((1/4+XP/125)^0.5-1/2)
Lua: returns 24
JavaScript: returns 639
```

If anyone knows how to make this formula work with JavaScript please provide an example below.
Thanks.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53184121/math-pow-alternative-in-lua

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `^` operator in Javascript does a [XOR operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or#Bitwise_operation), rather than raising something to a power. In recent versions of Javascript (Node.js 8 seems to support it, I'm not sure about earlier versions) you can use the `**` operator instead; if you need to support earlier versions, you should use `Math.pow()`.

```js
// newer code
Math.floor((1/4 + XP/125) ** 0.5 - 1/2)

// older code
Math.floor(Math.pow(1/4 + XP/125, 0.5) - 1/2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use like this:

```
Math.floor(Math.pow(1/4+(XP/125), 0.5)-1/2);
```